# import web image and hyperlink into html page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am trying to dynamically update my outlook email signature by editing the signature html file on my computer. I have done it where it pulls in an image that I have stored on a webpage (src="http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg") successfully. The image that is stored on the webpage has a hyperlink to a specific landing page on our website, but it doesn't import the link with the image.

Does anyone know how I would import the image AND the link? We update our email signatures monthly and by just uploading a new image (with the same file name) with a new link, I was hoping to have it pull it in automatically.

Thanks

Comment: It can't be done this way. The image will update since it's is downloaded each time someone views it. But you'll always need to update the signature's html manually if the link changes. Is how things work. Sorry. :/

Comment: I had a feeling. I've been testing for hours using different things, but when the image is viewed in the email, there is no link.